# how to convert boolean query for infix to post-fix notation

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

How can I convert a boolean query from post-fix to infix notation like these two examples:

*Example 1:*

```
infix : Tony and George
post-fix : Tony George and
```

*Example 2:*

```
infix : Tony and George or Lona
post-fix : Tony George and Lona or
```

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework. If it is, please add a `homework` tag.

Comment: Have you found a library doing it? Did you check NCalc?
I'm developing a commercial solution and in spite of simplicity of the task at first glance, I would prefer to use a library to avoid some possible bugs in such sensitive logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not writing the exact code which you want but i am giving you an idea about it.

you can simply use infix to postfix algorithm which we normally use of mathematical expressions.

you can find one alog here

http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/General/comp.programming/2007-12/msg00100.html

and in that algo you can replace operators with your desired Boolean operators(and ,or you can use them like a string also)

some days before i developed a code for infix to postfix in c++ so for reference you can take a look of that

http://peeyushchandel.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/infix-to-postfix-conversioncodealgo/